# How do I handle float in Core Data / iPhone?

Tags: core-data, ios4

I recently got started on Core Data, thanks to this tutorial :
http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iPhone_OS_Core_Data_Tutorial

My question is about handling types other than String.
For example let us say I want to add to the existing fields (name,address and phone : which are all String(s) in the example presented), the weight which I want to be a float in my entity.

How would I change the code to handle a float instead of a String ?

I already tried to change one of the fields to float in my entity. First letting the code as it is, and the program crashed. Then I tried to adjust the code in some ways but it did not work. I have the feeling it must be simple, but I can't get it right.

Thanks for any tip.

Answer (score 2):

you should use NSNumber for float (and access it with [myNumber floatValue]).
You can't use primitive values in CoreData entities - only objects. ( NSString, NSDate, NSNumber, NSData ... )

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am not sure I understand. I just go to the xxx.xcdatamodel and change one of the property attribute from String to Float and save. Then when I want to run the program it doesn't show any error. But it crashes at start (or it does not start). I am trying to figure out what to do.